# I want my body gradient to start after my header gradient

Tags: html, css

I want the body gradient to start right below where the header gradient ends.

Here is all the relevant [code](http://codepen.io/Vigrant/pen/2/1):

CSS:

```
#header
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:linear-gradient(#fff,#000); 
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
}
html
{
    height:100%;
}
body
{
    background:linear-gradient(#000,#fff);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id = header></div>
```

I've tried messing around with bottom-margin , but havn't had any luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a container? Seems a strange way to do it.

Comment: I am very new to web design so it probably is a strange way to do it :P

Comment: Ah ok. In that case you've selected the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a container div to do it.

[http://codepen.io/**anon**/pen/4070/1](http://codepen.io/__anon__/pen/4070/1)

Comment: This basically works but it creates a line of whitespace on the left side of the container, and then a line of whitespace on the right side of the header.

Comment: @Vigrant - this is because of the body's default margin. When starting a CSS project, it's good practice to build it on top of a [CSS Reset](http://www.cssreset.com/).

Comment: @egasimus - Yeah that fixed the problem. When you say I should build it on top of a CSS Reset do you mean I should put that CSS Reset code at the top of any CSS work I do?

Comment: @Vigrant - yup, that's how it's used :) This gives you the same set of default styles everywhere, regardless of browser defaults.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to this, is to add a third gradient onto your header to have a smoother transition onto the body's linear gradient.

For example: `background:linear-gradient(#fff, #000, #232323);` for your header.